# Push certain part of string to array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get each label and push it into array. I want to get just data and push it into array. Can you please help me.

```html
<div class="checkbox-group" data-fieldlabel="Date and Price">
    <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
  
  />
<label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035125"
    >10/9/21 - $148.50
</label>
</span>
<span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box"
  ><label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126"
    >10/16/21 - $132.00
</label>
</span>

</div>
```

jquery

```js
(function($){
    $('[data-fieldlabel=\'Date and Price\']').each(function() {
        myarray=[];
        var text = $('.check-box-label').text();
        myarray.push(text)
 
       console.log(myarray);
      
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I need this type of array: only date array

```
[
    "10/9/21","10/16/21 "
]
```

Comment: What's going on with your HTML? It seems a little broken

Comment: fixed. it is because of my code editor

Comment: Still looks pretty broken to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the *dates*, try something like this

```js
// simple regex for matching US date strings
const dateMatcher = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/

// select all the .check-box-label elements 
// within your data-fieldlabel container
const myarray = $("[data-fieldlabel='Date and Price'] .check-box-label")
  // filter for elements containing dates
  .filter((_, { textContent }) => dateMatcher.test(textContent))
  // map the elements to the text you want
  .map((_, { textContent }) => textContent.match(dateMatcher)[0])
  // extract the array
  .get()

console.log("myarray:", myarray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group" data-fieldlabel="Date and Price">
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
    <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035125">
      10/9/21 - $148.50
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
    <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">
      10/16/21 - $132.00
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

See [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) for details

---

And of course, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const dateMatcher = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/

const myarray = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-fieldlabel='Date and Price'] .check-box-label"))
  .filter(({ textContent }) => dateMatcher.test(textContent))
  .map(({ textContent }) => textContent.match(dateMatcher)[0])
```

Comment: i got error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: @David what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome browser.

Comment: got error here .map((_, { textContent }) => textContent.match(dateMatcher)?.[0])

Comment: Works fine in my Chrome (v94) but I've removed the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and replaced it with a _filter_ check instead

Comment: i got empty myarray,no value in console

Comment: Where? If you run the example in my answer do you see the dates in the array? If you get something different in your code, then your HTML must be different to what you've shown in your question (which is still broken btw)

Comment: nice @phil, it works. Actually I was looking solution for this one: can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747830/jquery-hide-options-of-past-and-future-data/69748454?noredirect=1#comment123288087_69748454

Comment: its similar question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747830/jquery-hide-options-of-past-and-future-data/69748454?noredirect=1#comment123288087_69748454